# Can someone explain every word of this Objective-C property declaration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm not familiar with Objective-C syntax, so could someone explain what every term means in the following line of code?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: take your time to read a tutorial and come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: I see there are two close votes.  I disagree with the reasons given.  The question is not in any sense vague and can easily be answered (see Vladimir's answer).  The question is, however, a case of "plz do my work for me kthx", so -1.

Comment: thank you all........ interesting people in here .. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- **@property** - is a objective-c syntax for declaring and optionally synthesizing accessor methods for instance variable. Read [official reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) for more details.
- **nonatomic** - means that synthesized getter method will return ivar directly without locking it for thread-safety
- **retain** - means that ivar will be retained in setter method
- **readonly** - the trick to make setter method "private" for class users - so only getter method will be visible for compiler. Usually in implementation file this property is redeclared without readonly attribute using custom category so that setter method can be used inside class itself.
- **NSManagedObjectContext*** - variable type
- **managedObjectContext** - variable name

Once again - best advice here is to read [Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) section in official documentation...

Comment: this answer is really very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

readonly accessor means only the getter method is synthesised. The value is read only.

retain accessor means this class retains the pointer, the previous value is released

nonatomic accessor means that no locking is applied to the synthesised getter

@property reveals this member for synthesis so that getters/setters can be created. Without it you would have to access the property directly.

NSManagedObjectContext is a type of object/class, and *managedObjectContext is a pointer to an instance of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir is correct.

But I will suggest you to read [Objective-C 2.0 reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) First for long run.